# How do I reset the Primary Key index to 1 using Visual Studio 2008 Server Explorer?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

How do I reset the Primary Key index to 1 using Visual Studio 2008 Server Explorer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have a table, with data, and you want to restart PK Identity numbering back to 1.

You'll have to delete all data and reset the seed on the identity column. This can be done all in one statement.

Create a new query by right-clicking on the database server or a table, and choose New query (or whatever command is similar):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable;
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do. Can I do it from the Server Explorer?

Comment: @B Seven: yes, right click on the db or a table, and hit New Query (or similar)

Comment: It is quite right that TRUNCATE is the correct way to do this.  You however have to make sure that no other table is referencing the table (using it as a part of it´s foreign key) then you cannot do truncate.

Answer (score 11):

To reset the IDENTITY value to one, use [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (‘YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE’, RESEED, 1)
```

Comment: Reseed to 0 if you want your first record to have an ID of 1